# Config React Router v6.14

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have problem about config React-Router v6.14 is how to get param from url to component. I had tried  reading React-router documentation about `createBrowserRouter` and `useParams` but I didn't understood and how to set up it. I had tried set up via code in this. Is this possible to do this?

```
import { createBrowserRouter, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/DefaultLayout";
import FormAuth from "../pages/auth/Auth";
import NotFound404 from "../pages/notfound404/NotFound404";

const GetParam: any = () => {
  let { authPath } = useParams<string>();
  return authPath;
};

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <DefaultLayout />,
  },
  {
    path: "/:authPath",
    element: <FormAuth name={GetParam()} />,
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    element: <NotFound404 />,
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useParams` hook, like all React hooks, can only be called from React functions and custom React hooks. You have a couple options available to you.

1. The `FormAuth` component should use `useParams` directly to access the `authPath` route path parameter.

   ```
   const FormAuth = () => {
     const { authPath } = useParams();
     const name = authPath;

     ...
   };
   ```
2. Create a wrapper component that can read the `authPath` route parameter and pass that value as the `name` prop to `FormAuth`.

   ```
   const FormauthWrapper = () => {
     const { authPath } = useParams();
     return <FormAuth name={authParam} />;
   };

   export const router = createBrowserRouter([
     {
       path: "/",
       element: <DefaultLayout />,
     },
     {
       path: "/:authPath",
       element: <FormAuthWrapper />,
     },
     {
       path: "*",
       element: <NotFound404 />,
     },
   ]);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, You have to use useParams on the given route, in your case, in FormAuth.
When you redirect "/anypath" the component will call useParams and get the params.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just render the FormAuth element on the given path (you don't need to have an additional function in your routes file) and in the component, you can get the parameter using the useParams hook. In your case you can use it like this:

```
const { authPath } = useParams();
```

authPath will be either undefined (if no value is provided) or the value itself.